# deleting and purging from keyvault using the azure cli capturing error messages

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-cli

Im using AzureCLI@2 in devops to execute (via powershell) cli commands to first delete and then purge.

If you delete a cert from the keyvault you cannot purge it until it is fully deleted.

The error handling is wierd with the CLI (you cant use try/catch (See https://rajbos.github.io/blog/2019/07/12/Azure-CLI-PowerShell)

An error messsage is produced when the item is still deleting and ALSO when the item has been purged.

I need to know the difference between these two scenarios. Any idea how I can actually get the error message?

Comment: Can you check and confirm if you get these error logs in Azure Monitor > Activity Log?

Answer (score 0):

If the azure cli command failed, you can find the error message on the log of task AzureCLI@2. Through it isnot output to the error stream in the task log. See below screenshot.

[image]

You can set the attribute `failOnStandardError` to `true`. And the errors will be output to the error stream in the log.

As the blog you mentioned pointed out `try/catch` is not working with azure cli, since azure cli commands are not designed for Powershell. You can also write to the error stream an error message just to indicate where the actual error message resides in the log:  See below:

```
$output = az keyvault key delete --name keyName --vault-name .. 
if(!$output){
   Write-Host "[Error] Error in deleting key keyName"
}
```